# Coherence Filter over multiple Caches

Tags: oracle-coherence

I have two caches in my application. I have to make an AND filter where the left part of the filter is to a cache "A" and the right part of the filter is to a cache "B".

Is this possible to do this?

My current filter is like:

```
AllFilter(  
    AllFilter(  
        EqualsFilter(PofExtractor(target=VALUE, navigator=SimplePofPath(indices=0)), 1),   
        EqualsFilter(PofExtractor(target=VALUE, navigator=SimplePofPath(indices=1)), C)  
    ),   
    AndFilter(  
        GreaterFilter(PofExtractor(target=VALUE, navigator=SimplePofPath(indices=4)), 1998-12-31 00:00:00.0),   
        OrFilter(  
            AndFilter(  
                EqualsFilter(PofExtractor(target=VALUE, navigator=SimplePofPath(indices=33)), S),   
                GreaterFilter(PofExtractor(target=VALUE, navigator=SimplePofPath(indices=27)), 280)  
            ),   
            AndFilter(  
                EqualsFilter(PofExtractor(target=VALUE, navigator=SimplePofPath(indices=33)), N),   
                GreaterFilter(PofExtractor(target=VALUE, navigator=SimplePofPath(indices=26)), 280)  
            )  
        )  
    )  
)
```

the problem is that this extractors have to act over differents caches. If all the conditions are in the same cache, the code would be:

```
list.addAll(cacheA.keySet(myFilter));
```

but actually the filter is over three different caches:

```
cacheA -> 
    AllFilter(  
        EqualsFilter(PofExtractor(target=VALUE, navigator=SimplePofPath(indices=0)), 1),   
        EqualsFilter(PofExtractor(target=VALUE, navigator=SimplePofPath(indices=1)), C)  
    )

cacheB -> 
    GreaterFilter(PofExtractor(target=VALUE, navigator=SimplePofPath(indices=4)), 1998-12-31 00:00:00.0)  

cacheC and CacheA -> 
    OrFilter(  
            AndFilter(  
                CacheA --> EqualsFilter(PofExtractor(target=VALUE, navigator=SimplePofPath(indices=33)), S),   
                CacheB --> GreaterFilter(PofExtractor(target=VALUE, navigator=SimplePofPath(indices=27)), 280)  
            ),   
            AndFilter(  
                CacheA --> EqualsFilter(PofExtractor(target=VALUE, navigator=SimplePofPath(indices=33)), N),   
                CacheB --> GreaterFilter(PofExtractor(target=VALUE, navigator=SimplePofPath(indices=26)), 280)  
            )  
        )  
    )
```

kindest regards

Comment: it looks like you want to implement
if (CacheA.getValue() == CacheB.getValue())
 return A.

is it right?

Answer (score 0):

Eventually you'll have to make two queries, It will help if you'll describe your use case.

It's possible to make it better by accessing more than one cache with [EntryProcessor](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/coherence/COHDG/api_processcache.htm#COHDG5201), which is a peace of code running on the cache itself, it gives your better performance and integrity.

**NOTE**: both caches should belong to the same [Service](https://blogs.oracle.com/felcey/entry/coherence_clustering_principles), otherwise it won't work.

Comment: Hi, I have added more detail to my question. I would appreciate If you could guide me in the implementation. Kindest regards